# Environmentalists are annoying me, how can I silence them?

Tags: tropico-4

I haven't been very environment-friendly and now the environmentalists are on my heels. My reputation with them is very low, especially because I cut some trees and dug for gold.

What's the best way to get back on their good side?

I tried recycling and putting up some gardens, but that doesn't really seem to be enough to make them like me again.

Are there any tricks to make environmentalists happy while still making a profit with the earth's natural resources?

Comment: Make out with a tree.

Comment: Optional tasks are good for this.

Comment: This question is off topic. This forum is for gaming... :D

Comment: It's a universal problem I think. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Planting trees, building botanical gardens and issuing anti-pollution edicts helps.

Make sure all your applicable industries have pollution-reducing options enabled; build a garbage dump somewhere out of sight of the city but within operating reach, and have it recycle and use high temperature burners.

Praise the environmentalists during your speeches - it's a +10 bonus that doesn't cost you anything.

Try not to bulldoze areas of high natural beauty for industry sites.

Keep an eye out for subtasks from their faction; they may not always be things you /want/ to do, but it's worth hearing them out to see what they want.

EDIT: Can't remember why I forgot to add this originally, but *shacks cause lots of pollution*. Make sure everyone has *somewhere* at least halfway decent to live.

Comment: How far is the "operating reach" of the garbage dump? Can I place it outside of the red (polluted) area and it still has effect?

Comment: Yes. I don't recall the actual range offhand, but I think road accessibility probably has an effect on it as well (speaking of which; make sure your road network is up to scratch. All cars pollute, but traffic jams and gridlocks mean lots of cars in the same area, *causing pollution without actually getting anywhere*

Comment: The range of a garbage dump is pretty huge; you can check it directly in the overlays, and it's not affected by road networks. It's under Island Conditions, and there's an option to see Landfill Coverage. Since the Environmentalists complain about "insufficient landfill coverage," it's useful to see when you have a far-flung mine or farm that isn't covered.

Answer (score 16):

If all else fails, you can always just perform the Outlaw Faction edict and get rid of them entirely.  You just need a little preparation in advance with some secret police and a sizable army to quell any possible rebellion.

Comment: Hm, tempting... \*evil laugh\*

Comment: This solution may not be 'optimal,' but really, its the most thoroughly *Tropico* answer available.

Comment: Yeah, upvote for getting into the spirit of Tropico!

Comment: +1 for answering the question - that definitely counts as 'silencing' them!

Answer (score 9):

Here are some things to try.

- Make sure you have enough recycling, a large city may need several dumps.  There is an overlay that shows garbage coverage.
- Pass some of the environmentally friendly edicts like Pollution control and Anti-Litter ordinance.
- Watch for optional tasks that can boost your faction rep quickly.
- Take a look at the faction leader and see what else he is interested in.  If you can make him generally happy, it will improve your relationship with the faction overall.  If all else fails, you can always try bribing him.
- Don't worry about them.  You don't need to please all the factions all the time.  If they start performing eco-protests, just make some of them disappear and they should be scared off.